# WPF: Textbox Binding with StringFormat={}{0:F2}. Don't show zero's

Tags: wpf, binding, string-formatting

I am binding an object to a TextBox with the following XAML:

`<TextBox Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=MyValue, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}{0:F2}}" />`

Naturally when I bind a new object (which values are all still zero) the Text property is set to `0.00`. I have several of these TextBoxes, which makes it tedious to delete every value before entering a new one.

At the moment I'm clearing these boxes in the `Window_Loaded` method using the [FindVisualChildren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type) method.

It just feels clunky though. Is there a neat way of doing this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the following:

`StringFormat={}{0:#.##}`

It will format to two decimal places and won't show zeroes.