# formatting textbox without binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, formatting

very simple question: is it possible to format a textbox without binding? I have a textbox which is not bound to anything, and I want to format it as currency.

Comment: you could create a behavior for this. i dont know if there is a built in way

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820093/textbox-in-wpf-and-text-format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820093/textbox-in-wpf-and-text-format)