# Can I create an extension method for a WPF UserControl that can return a list of its controls?

Tags: wpf

Is this possible while the controls are not publicly exposed through properties ?

Answer (score 3):

this is easy to achive: (code from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type))

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If a control is part of the `Visual Tree` of that `UserControl`, then yes, you can list all the visual children of that control. And you can wrap that logic in an extension method.

You can use `VisualTreeHelper` class for it.