# WPF - clear all textboxes in tabcontrol not working

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, wpf-controls

I have an application with a tab control and several textboxes in each tab and when the user says so, I would like every text box in the window (called MainWindow) to be cleared. I used the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type), but it only seems to work for the textboxes in the tab that it is in focus.

Comment: please check if my solution worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
void ClearTextBoxes(DependencyObject obj)
{
    TextBox tb = obj as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
        tb.Text = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj as DependencyObject); i++)
        ClearTextBoxes(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i));
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ClearTextBoxes(this);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be having a different effect to my current method.

Comment: When I clear the textboxes, only the textboxes contained in the tab in focus are cleared.

Comment: I've just created an array with each of the tabs in. I looped them through your function and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try replace calls to `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildren` with `LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren`

LogicalTreeHelper gets the actual visual tree. usually this is way more than the logical tree, but in this case since the other tabs are not visible - the visual sub-tree in those tabs doesn't get created.
The LogicalTree should still be there though, so that should work.