# How do I search for the Group types in the Visual Tree?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

In WPF datagrid you are able to do groupings on the ICollectionView and the datagrid knows how to render them accordingly.

While I can tell from the ICollectionView how many groups I have, I don;t know where on Screen they are.  I would like to know when a Group is currently shown on my screen.

Therefore, I would like to know how I would search for any "group" type within a range of rows.  Is this possible?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution here:

[Find all controls in WPF Window by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)