# Equate array of controls to existing control

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays

I tried something like:

```
RadioButton[] diff = new RadioButton[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    diff[i] = (RadioButton)Control("rad_D" + i.ToString());
}
```

Clearly does not work. But what was the correct way?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to find all the RadioButtons with names of "rad_D*x*"?

Comment: @MattBurland: Something like that. I have several radiobuttons named "rad_D0", "rad_D1"... Then I wanted to add them to an array of radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Ok, so you are looking for already existing RadioButtons, in that case, use FindName. Something like this:

```
RadioButton[] diff = new RadioButton[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    diff[i] = someparentControl.FindName("rad_D" + i.ToString()) as RadioButton;
}
```

You need a parent control, which can just be the window itself as it will search recursively for a matching name.

Comment: I dont want to create radiobuttons. They are created anyway. I just want to equate array of radiobuttons to already existing radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if the radio buttons are direct children of a *Panel* such as a Grid, StackPanel etc then you can do this:

```
var buttons = grid.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().
    Where(rb => rb.Name.StartsWith("rad_D").ToList();
```

to obtain a List, or if you really want an array

```
var buttons = grid.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().
    Where(rb => rb.Name.StartsWith("rad_D").ToArray();
```

And you can use this article [Find all controls in WPF Window by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type) which has several methods for finding all controls of a specific type.