# clear screen from buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Im trying to delete all the buttons in my WinForm.But somehow, it keeps few buttons in the form.
How can I remove all the buttons in my form?What is the mistake at my code?!

```
void ClearScreen()
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Button)
                this.Controls.Remove(c);

        }


    }
```

Comment: Why you need to remove them? Can you provide more information? May be just hide/collapse them using binding and corresponding converter?

Btw you just cycle thru children of current control, so you need to write recursive method and call it on every child

Comment: what? I am showing a sequence in this form. and I want to show a Different sequence when the user want. So I need to get rid from the buttons in my form, and activate new one's.

Comment: I tried your code and it is working. What is the error you get?

Comment: I don't get any error. It just do not remove all the buttons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all controls in WPF Window by type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)

Comment: Slap your controls on a frame and hide that. You don't want to remove all controls.

Comment: @CodeCaster how do i do that?

Comment: @Noam650 For some reason it is not removing the last button. Check my answer, that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code doesn't work is that you are modifying a collection while you are using the enumerator to loop through it.

Comment: Not unless you put them in a single panel and remove the panel.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void ClearScreen()
{
    List<Button> _buttons = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();

    foreach (var button in _buttons)
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(button);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Button btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
            {
                this.Controls.Remove(bbb);
            }
```

this is a generic way to remove all the buttons from a form