# How to Access control inside datagrid ColumnHeaderStyle?

Tags: wpf, styles, wpfdatagrid

How to Access control  inside  datagrid ColumnHeaderStyle?

in this sample:

```
   <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid Name="grdPeresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                       <TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="2"  PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="grid1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" >
                           </TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="grd" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource theSource}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
              ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}"  PreviewKeyDown="grd_PreviewKeyDown"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
              behavior:MouseDoubleClick.Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}" 
              GridLinesVisibility="Vertical">
    </DataGrid>
```

i want to access for example to textSearch of first Column of datagrid.is it possible?how?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type) :

```
 var res = FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(grd).Where(t => t.Name == "txtSearch");
```

here yo can find all "txtSearch" headers textBox.

I'm sure it can get more direct way, but until then ..