# move keyboard focus to next treeitem?

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have an application that uses treeview in wpf with mvvm.  The treeitem template contains a textbox for the user to enter or change field data. I would like if the user presses tabwhile editing if it would move to the next visible treeitem textbox and allow them to start editing that. Is this possible? I can catch the tab key but can't figure out how to move to the next item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm not sure it's the cleanest way but I found a way to do it and it doesn't seem to be suffering from speed issues so it works for now, still would be interested in a cleaner answer if anyone has one.  Here is what I did:

I used a method similar to the one referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type) to get a collection of all the textboxes in the TreeView.  I then used 'sender' for the KeyDown event, cast to a textbox, and got it's datacontext which is my view model for that node.  I then used my overall viewmodel to find the view model of the next visible node (very easy with a two way binding to 'IsExpanded').  Last, I iterated over all of the textboxes found at the start until I found one who's datacontext was the next visible view model and called Keyboard.Focus(myTextBox) on it.

Like I said, it seems like there should be a cleaner way but it works for now...