# Converting Windows Forms to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Following is part of my code in Windows Forms application, how can I convert it to WPF, considering `this.Controls` is not available:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                tb.Enter += textBox_Enter;
            }
        }

        void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            focusedTextbox = (TextBox)sender;
        }

private TextBox focusedTextbox = null;

private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (focusedTextbox != null)
            {
                focusedTextbox.Text += "1";

            }
        }
```

Comment: There may be no `Controls` property on a WPF `Window`, but you can enumerate objects with a `VisualTreeHelper` or a `LogicalTreeHelper`.  With [the code in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/978352/559103) you can enumerate all visible `TextBox`es with `foreach (TextBox tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(myWindow))`

Answer (score 0):

Listen to [`PreviewGotKeyboardFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewgotkeyboardfocus.aspx) on your root element (most likely the Window itself) and record the [`e.NewFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardfocuschangedeventargs.newfocus.aspx) argument.  Preview events bubble up the visual tree, so any control that exposes one within a parent control will trigger it (see [routed events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)).

The event handler becomes:

```
    private void OnGotFocusHandler(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var possiblyFocusedTextbox = e.NewFocus as TextBox;
        //since we are now receiving all focus changes, the possible textbox could be null
        if (possiblyFocusedTextbox != null)
            focusedTextbox = possiblyFocusedTextbox;
    }
```