# How to target all buttons inside Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have several buttons in my `WPF` Window. How can I target all buttons inside the window regardless if they are inside `Stack panels` or `Dock Panels`. I want to target all of them to be able to change the background color of all of them through settings.

Rather than targeting each individual name of the button, is there another method?

Comment: do you want to change the colors during runtime or just change all the colors once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this question [Find all controls in WPF Window by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)

It shows how to get all the controls in a WPF application, and then you can set your background color of your buttons.

```
foreach (Button btn in FindVisualChildren<Button>(window))
{
    btn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
```

`FindVisualChildren` is from the linked answer.

Comment: I have voted to delete my answer as this one is clearly correct and you were first to answer , mine would only cause confusion

Answer (score 2):

Define a style for button in resources without giving key name. It will be automatically applied to all buttons in window.

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
```

hope it helps..