# How do i get a page instance from a frame?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, frame

I have a frame that i initialized in xaml like this:

```
<window>
   <Frame Name="myframe" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Source="mypage.xaml"/>
</window>
```

I'm trying to get the page instance from the window that contains the frame (which in order contains the page) in c# code and i don't know how to get it.

```
public partial class mywindow : Window
    {
        public mywindow()
        {
            BusinessLogic.Initialize();
            InitializeComponent();
            var a = myframe.Content;
         }
}
```

how do i get it?

thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Just so you know, we need to see [what you have tried first](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/); before we can truly help you.  So, post up your code thus far!

Comment: thank you very much!  i tried :  var a = myframe.Content;

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.  Please post your code in your original post :)

Answer (score 7):

Your code is correct, but lack cast the return of Content.

```
public partial class mywindow : Window
    {
        public mywindow()
        {
            BusinessLogic.Initialize();
            InitializeComponent();
            var a = (MyPage)myframe.Content;
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this solution should do the trick?

[Find all controls in WPF Window by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)

```
 FindVisualChildren<Frame>(this).FirstOrDefault()
```