# How to change the color of inside circle of radio button in WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, radio-button, controltemplate

This is my radio button:

```
<RadioButton Content="Add" Grid.Column="1" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,13,0,0" Name="rdAdd" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="AddEditRadio" Checked ="rdAdd_Checked" FontSize="12.667" />
```

Now the color of inner circle of radio button is orange.I want to change it to blue.

Which property do I set to get "Blue" color?

Comment: K T - why have you accepted only 4 answers for you 16 questions? And why do you ignore any comments?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no direct property you can use to change the color.
What you need to do is reTemplate the RadioButton to whatever you would like.

Luckily, the default templates are available, **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751600.aspx)** is the one for the RadioButton.

If I understand correctly what you want to change, you should probably modify the color of the `CheckMark` (or the entire `BulletDecorator` depends what you're trying to achieve).

Answer (score 2):

`<RadioButton Content="Add" Background="Blue" Foreground="Green" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" />`

(i added BorderThickness of 5 to make it easier to see)

This will change the background color of the radio button to blue, the text "ADD" to green, and the border (around the button) red, like this:

[image: radio button, selected and unselected]

These are the only colors you can directly change from Radio button (without using templates and such)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but in case someone else is looking to change the color of the checked circle inside a radio button, this worked for me without changing the control template:

(1) On the loaded event of the radio button, use a find visual children function (get one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)) to locate the ellipse in the visual tree beneath the button.

(2) Change the fill and/or the stroke of the ellipse found in step (1) to the desired color.

(3) That's it!

Comment: Code in case someone needs it: 
        private void RadioButton_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var rb = sender as RadioButton;
            var ellipse = rb.FindChildByType<Ellipse>();
            ellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 153, 204));
        }

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of radiobutton. You can use blend and update the control template there.