# How to access controls inside an ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

Using Windows Phone 8, C#.

What I've done is basically done is edited the pivot item. I've named it `MainPivot` and inside that I've edited the Pivot Item Title and added a `TextBlock` inside it called `PivotTitletxt`. XAML for that is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate3">
  <TextBlock x:Name="PivotTitletxt" Height="34" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" Width="447"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

How can I access this e.g. when setting opacity or changing foreground? so that I can use it on my MainPage like e.g. PivotTitletxt.Opacity = 30; ...

Thanks!

Comment: Follow the link.. http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/how-access-named-control

Comment: Yea I found that a bit confusing. I just need a good sample where it involves my problem.

Comment: What was the thing you get confused?

Comment: The whole thing :\ I have tried the visual tree way but I don't think I got any luck.

Comment: did you try the VisualTree after the `Loaded`?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work in the first place.

Comment: If you look through the VisualTree before the page load, VisualTree ll not generated... so try it after the Loaded..

Comment: I'll try again and Let you know.

Comment: I've tried it again but I just cant get it. Stuck pretty much everywhere.

Comment: did you try my solution based on the @Sankarann website?

Comment: Use data binding. change the value of a property of a view model

Answer (score 1):

The link @Sankarann gave you is a pretty good example.

I'll try to put it on your scenario:

Your MainPivot has PivotItems right? So What you have to do on the Loaded event is:

```
var _mainPivot = MainPivot as Pivot
foreach (var _pivotItem in _mainPivot.Items)
{
var _container = _mainPivot.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(_pivotItem);
var _children = AllChildren(_container)
var _name = "PivotTitletxt";
var _control = (TextBlock)_Children.first(x=>x.Name == _name);
_control.Opacity  = 30;

}
```

Then copy the AllChildren method exactly as the it is in the site.

The code above, might have a few adjustments because I've done it without VS...

Hope it helps.

Regards,

============ new answer ==============

[Find all controls in WPF Window by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then try :

```
TextBlock xx = FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(mainPivot).FirsOrDefault(x=>x.name=="PivotTitletxt");

if(xx!=null)
xx.opacity = 30
```

Once again, this come might need some correction...i'm doing it by heart, without VS.

Try it out

Comment: I managed to get the thing sorted but now It keeps saying that `Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Controls.Control' to 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock'` What do you think I should do?

Comment: can you show me the line where it is giving that error?

Comment: It's this line: `var _Control = (TextBlock)_Children.First(x => x.Name == _Name);`

Comment: Try replacing Control by FrameworkElement in the AllChildren method. The reason is that Textblock inherits from FrameworkElement and TextBox from System.Windows.Control

Comment: I'll give you another solution in one minute

Comment: Ok. So I think there is a problem in the item being found. Remember that the textblock "PivotTitleTxt" is inside the MainPivot's Title template not the Pivot Items template. Could there be a problem in those areas. Searching for the wrong template? It keeps saying that the item has no matching name etc..

Comment: Seems like even that didn't work. The other alternative way might be the way @Shawn Kendrot mentioned. DataBinding. Oh well thanks for your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48529/discussion-between-sexta13-and-ahmed-c)