# Clear all TextBox in Window

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, wpf-controls

I'm programming in c#(WPF). I have a lot of `nested controls`. I want to `clear all` of my TextBox control which are in my application. It is very hard to access them by their name. Is there any way to access them `recursively` and clear them?

for example some thing like this:

```
public void ClearAll(Control c)
{
    if(c is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)c).Clear();
        return;
    }

    foreach(Control child in GetChild(c))
    {
        ClearAll(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `XAML` for `TextBox` and from there it will be easier to clear them using CommandBindings or something similar.

Comment: you  may  take a look at this  answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type

Comment: Assuming these controls are bound, can you call a "reset" function on their bound objects, which could then set the text to String.Empty?

Comment: I immigrated from WinForm to Xaml and I do'nt now about CommandBindings a lot.

Comment: Reset function? for what? how?

Comment: Rule #1 in WPF. "WPF is not WinForms"! You should probably start looking into bindings and how to set them up. You should (almost) never have to access a control by its name or manipulate it in code at all. Nearly any modification you can think of is doable through bindings.

Comment: Are your text boxes bound? I can help if they are, or perhaps guide you on setting up those bindings otherwise.

Comment: @Babak.Abad Now is the perfect time to learn them if you just migrated from `WinForms` :) It'll make your life easier without having to find all controls recursively and clear them one by one, instead use one command that'll clear them using commands. IMO.

Comment: More generally put, do some research on MVVM and how it applies to WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VisualTreeHelper class comes handy. You can use it like this:

```
static public void TraverseVisualTree(Visual myMainWindow)
    {
        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myMainWindow);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var visualChild = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myMainWindow, i);
            if (visualChild is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)visualChild;
                tb.Clear();
            }
            TraverseVisualTree(visualChild);
        }
    }
```