# Creating a MouseEnter Event for every Button in a window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been working on an application months ago, my friend and i wanted to share this application with other friends, and i need to display some help to make the application easier  because it was designed only for both of us.

The idea that came out is to display help on a text Block every time a hover event is popped from a button. So we added a textBlock. Now the problem that we still facing is how to create the Hover Event for every button in our Main Window, there are a lots of buttons in this window, So we can't add an event to every button in the XAML code.

What i am expecting from this answer is a way to add Hover Event to all buttons in the main window Programmatically  ?

EDIT: after some googling and help, i can do the following :

```
foreach (UIElement btn in GeneralMenuGrid.Children)
        {
            if (btn is Button)
            {
                Button currentButton = (Button)btn;
                currentButton.Content = "test";
            }

        }
```

This is just a test that will allow all the buttons in the GeneralMenuGrid control to have a content : test, now the problem again is that i have nested controls in this grid, how can i reach them?

EDIT : after years of goggling i got to loop through all the buttons in my window with this :

```
public static void EnumVisuals(Visual argVisual, Window currentWindow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(argVisual); i++)
        {
            Visual childVisual = (Visual) VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(argVisual, i);
            if (childVisual is Button)
            {
                var button = childVisual as Button;
                button.MouseEnter += AllButtonsOnMouseEnter;
            }


            EnumVisuals(childVisual, currentWindow);
        }
    }
```

now in the AllButtonsOnMouseEnter function, i can't access a button, i made it public... i can't access it from this class, how can i send the window with the event arguments?

Comment: It sounds like you want use the [ToolTip property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.frameworkelement.tooltip.aspx), perhaps in conjunction with the [ToolTip control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.tooltip.aspx)

Comment: @elgonzo i don't want to use a popup window, the text will be displayed in a textblock in the same window

Comment: @elgonzo is there a way to just loop throught button controls and foreach one create a hover event ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

after a lot of googling and chat help... i finally did it, maybe other will be interested this is how i proceeded :

i created a static recursive function that will get all the buttons in the window:

```
public static void EnumVisuals(Visual argVisual, Button toModifyButton)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(argVisual); i++)
        {
            Visual childVisual = (Visual) VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(argVisual, i);
            if (childVisual is Button)
            {
                var button = childVisual as Button;
                button.MouseEnter += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    toModifyButton.Content = "Get the Help text from database if you want";
                };
            }


            EnumVisuals(childVisual, toModifyButton);
        }
    }
```

**why do you send a Button :**

i need to write the help in a button, and the only way i found to access it's content property is to send it via this function and of course make it public.

Hope you'll find this helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote, "there are a lots of buttons in this window, so we can't add an event to every button in the XAML code." But you can - just add a style that applies to all buttons:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="Button_MouseEnter"/>
</Style>
```

I don't know how you intend to get the help text relevant to each Button, but it's easy to store it in the Button's Tag:

```
<Button Tag="Instantly move from one place to another.">
Teleport
</Button>
```

Then write an event handler that shows the help in your TextBlock:

```
private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    textblock_that_shows_help.Text = button.Tag;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created an extension method that does this, adapted from here: [Find all controls in WPF Window by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)

Put this class somewhere in your project:

```
public static class VisualTreeSearch
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds all elements of the specified type in the <see cref="System.Windows.DependencyObject"/>'s visual tree using a breadth-first search.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of element to search for.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="root">The object to search in.</param>
    /// <returns>A list of elements that match the criteria.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(this DependencyObject root) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        return root.Find<T>(false, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds all elements of the specified type in the <see cref="System.Windows.DependencyObject"/>'s visual tree.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of element to search for.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="root">The object to search in.</param>
    /// <param name="depthFirst">True to do a depth-first search; false to do a breadth-first search</param>
    /// <param name="includeRoot">True to include the root element in the search; false to exclude it</param>
    /// <returns>A list of elements that match the criteria.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(this DependencyObject root, bool depthFirst, bool includeRoot) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (includeRoot)
        {
            var depRoot = root as T;
            if (depRoot != null)
                yield return depRoot;
        }

        var searchObjects = new LinkedList<DependencyObject>();
        searchObjects.AddFirst(root);

        while (searchObjects.First != null)
        {
            var parent = searchObjects.First.Value;
            var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            var insertAfterNode = depthFirst ? searchObjects.First : searchObjects.Last;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                var depChild = child as T;
                if (depChild != null)
                    yield return depChild;
                insertAfterNode = searchObjects.AddAfter(insertAfterNode, child);
            }
            searchObjects.RemoveFirst();
        }
    }
}
```

To use the extension method, write the following in your window class (as an example). This code loops through all children, grandchildren, etc. of `this` (which should be your Window in this case) and finds all `Button` elements.

```
foreach (var button in this.Find<Button>())
{
    button.MouseEnter += button_MouseEnter;
}

...

private void button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```