# Link Ellipse image with class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am making a pool game as my project. I am having troubles of declaring the ellipse image to link with the class so that I can use it with the physics engine later on. I was left with this code to finish and I've already research for 5 hours just to figure out this problem.

---

At XAML

```
<Ellipse Canvas.Left="314" Canvas.Top="305" Height="35" Name="Ball1" Stroke="Black" Width="35" StrokeThickness="0.01">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/FYPJ;component/Images/Balls/1.png" />
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
```

---

Class

```
  public Point Position { get; set; }
  public int BallNum
    {
        get
        {
            return ballNum;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 7)
                IsSolid = true;
            else
                IsSolid = false;
            ballNum = value;
        }
    }
public Ball(int ballNumber, Point position)
    {
        this.BallNum = ballNumber;
        this.Position = position;
        // TODO: rember to add physics behavior later
    }
```

---

At XAML.cs

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // init ball position
        foreach (Ball ball in balls)
        {
            Ellipse ballImage = this.GetBallImage(ball);
            Console.WriteLine("ball " + ball.BallNum); // For Testing according to my teacher
            ball.Position.X = ; // Unfinished Code
            ball.Position.Y = ; // Unfinished Code


        }
```

### }

If you think there are still code that I missed out on this question. Feel free to comment it out. Thank you.

Comment: You have problem in code behind to obtain ellipse property defined in xaml? [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/974598/1997232).

Comment: Yes. I was told to get the coordinates of the ellipse image in order for me to define the ellipse image to the class. I'm not really sure how to do it.

Comment: Give ellipse a name in xaml: `<Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" ...`, then you can access it from code by using that name: `ball.Position.X = ellipse.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);`

Comment: I am having this type of error: An object of a type convertible to 'System.Windows.Point' is required

Comment: Try `ball.Position = new Point((double)ellipse.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty), (double)ellipse.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty));`