# How show an UIElement like MessageBox in current display frame. [ Windows Phone 8.0+ ]

Tags: c#, android, windows-phone, messagebox, toast

My question is how can I show an UIElement for some time (ex. 5s) in current display frame when application is running foreground. Example ToastPrompt from Coding4Fun library or native MessageBox. My goal is to show something like Android style Toast Notification. Can you give me some help?

Here is what I want make but on Windows Phone:

[image: Goal sample image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom `UserControl` with layout you need and animation to display it for seconds

When you need to show your `UserControl` - get an instance of current `Page` `((App.Current as App).RootFrame` and find root element to add your control to. Look at [VisualTreeHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type) class, which can help you to do this