# WPF - Clear all textBox via code after pressing a button

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've some `texBox` where the users has to input some data.

```
textBox1
textBox2
textBox3
textBox4
```

After filling those `textBox`, the users presses on a button and other stuff is done.

I want to clear all the `textBox` as soon as the users clicks on the button.

I know I can do it by one by one using `.clear`

```
textBox1.clear();
textBox2.clear();
textBox3.clear();
textBox4.clear();
```

But this looks a bit *dirty* for me as I have more than 4 textBoxes.

So I was thinking about looping from 1 to `number_of_textboxes` and then `.clean` each one, but I dont know how can I get the `number_of_texboxes`. Is there a way to get it so I can make this loop, or any other easy way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the helper method from the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type).

Assuming you want to clear all the textbox from a specific parent (i.e. window), you can call it like foreach (TextBox textbox in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(parentWindow))
{
    // TODO: Clear textbox
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through all of the elements in the UI and extract just the `Textbox`es, but it's hardly efficient, compared with your direct code. However, you could do that with a recursive method using the [`VisualTreeHelper` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
GetChildrenOfType<TextBox>(this).ToList().ForEach(textBox => textBox.Clear());
```

...

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetChildrenOfType<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (dependencyObject != null)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); index++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, index);
            if (child != null && child is T) yield return (T)child;
            foreach (T childOfChild in GetChildrenOfType<T>(child)) yield return childOfChild;
        }
    }
}
```

This of course assumes that `this` is the parent control of the relevant `TextBox`es... if not, you could call something like this:

```
GetChildrenOfType<TextBox>(ParentGrid).ToList().ForEach(textBox => textBox.Clear());
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat similar as Sheridan says:

```
 void ClearAllTextBoxes(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            if (obj is TextBox)
                ((TextBox)obj).Text = null;
            LoopVisualTree(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i));
        }
    }
```

However for WPF it's often better to clear out the objects to which the textboxes are bound. This makes sure your logic isn't dependent on a UI implementation.