# WPF - put the name of every textblock in an array

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to know if it's possible to let my code scan every name of every textblock in my XAML file and put it into an array.

for example:

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" />
```

C#:

```
string[] textblocknames = new string[] { "textBlock1", "2", ... };
```

I know how to scan for controls by type, which has been explained here: [Find all controls in WPF Window by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type). But I don't know how to find the names and put it in an array.

I want to use this to put borders around it, and it would look similiar to this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < textblocknames.Length; i++)
        {
            Border brd = new Border();
            brd.Name = string.Format("border_{0}", i);
            brd.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 1, 1);
            brd.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
            brd.Child = textblocknames[i]
        }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are so many textblocks in my XAML file that I don't want to add these borders manually, and it's handy to know, in my opinion and I`m also curious

Comment: You want get all textblocks and change borders, or you want just get textblocks names?

Answer (score 0):

You can search all texblocks in this way:
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/978352/2050745). You can get names for every textblock in foreach loop like: `tb.text`, and put them to array.
You can add border in this way:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < textblocknames.Length; i++)
        {
            Border brd = new Border();
            brd.Name = string.Format("border_{0}", i);
            brd.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 1, 1);
            brd.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
            object item = GridName.FindName(textblocknames[i]);
            brd.Child = item;
        }
```

Comment: Can you give a small example, I think I don't really get it

Comment: You write you want find names and put them to array? Yes please.

Comment: I refresh answer. You have problem to set border child.

Comment: yeah because it can't convert the object to a UIElement. And if you could give an example on how I should use the solution from the other thread in my code I will mark this as correct answer ;)

Comment: You run this in another thread or just in different form or class?

Comment: I meant the thread you linked in your reaction which says SOLUTION

Comment: This is just functon. You can use your old, or add this and call this function which return objects.

Comment: That object doesn't even work though. Thanks for the help anyway, I`ll be adding the borders manually now. P.S. you need to improve your grammar a bit!