# Set the width of scrollbars programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application, which uses WPF on windows as toolkit framework. Now I would like to set the width of scrollbars for my ScrollViewers programmatically. I found many examples to set the width via XAML. But how can I define the width of scrollbars programmatically?

Unfortunately I could not find any property or method on ScrollViewer to set the width of scrollbars.

```
var viewer = new ScrollViewer();
viewer.MagicProperty = 42; // Does not exist
```

Also all properties on SystemParameters are unfortunately read-only.

```
VerticalScrollBarWidth.VerticalScrollBarWidth = 42; // Read-only
```

Edit: WPF is only one of multiple toolkit frameworks in my application. I use a custom GUI abstraction layer for supporting Windows (WPF), Linux (GTK#) and MacOS X (in future). My user interface is encapsulated in an OS independent way. Therefore it makes no sense to use XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to set `x:Name` property, then you can access `ScrollViewer` in your code.

Or use Binding: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_data_binding.htm

`Binding` will be useful if you want to manipulate with multile `ScrollViewers` and set same values.

EDIT:
You can create ScrollViewer in your code and then set its parameters. But you need a way to insert it into VisualTree among other controls. So you need to get instance of some container and then use its `Children.Add()` method

However I'd really recommend to use as much XAML as you can and leave your code for application logic, not the UI building.

EDIT 2:
Can you try:

```
            Style myStyle = new Style(typeof(ScrollBar));
            myStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(WidthProperty, 40));

            scrollViewer.Style = myStyle;
```

**EDIT 3:**
I found a solution. You can add `ResourceDictionary.xaml` and add this style to it:

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="35" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="35" />
    </Style>
```

Then load it at runtime like so:

```
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(@"Dictionary.xaml", UriKind.Relative)) as
                ResourceDictionary);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I need a way without any XAML.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "without any XAML"? My approach is programmatic, you just need a way to tell which scrollViewer to change.

Comment: The linked website shows a data binding tutorial, based on XAML examples. I need pure C# or VB.NET code, like _new ScrollViewer().ScrollBarWith = 42_ or _SystemParameters.ScrollBarWith = 42_. Both examples don't work of course. But I hope that they clarifies for what I'm looking.

Comment: That is certainly possible, just unnecessary complicated. If you don't want can't set x:Name then you must find your ScrolViewer using VisualTree - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type

Comment: I have all ScrollViewer instances. This is not the problem. But I cannot find any property or method to set the scroll bar width. In SystemParameters all properties are unfortunately read-only. I have nothing against x:Name if I would know a way to use it without having any XAML files.

Comment: I have extended my question. I hope that you can understand my problem better now.

Comment: Throws an InvalidOperationException: "TargetType 'ScrollBar'" does not match the element type "ScrollViewer" (original text translated into English)

Comment: Thank you very much! Until now, the API of WPF was very logical and self-describing. Therefore I haven't expected that changing the scroll bar width could require such a workaround.