# C# windows store app / Generate PDF programmatically using Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-store-apps

I want to generate PDF file programmatically using `Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager`.

I'm looking to do **Microsoft Print to PDF** programmatically without opening below dialog.

[image]

I searched in google and find lots of results. but I'm not able to find any solution that's working.

Here are the few links that I've searched:
[How to Silent print from an UWP Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984595/how-to-silent-print-from-an-uwp-application/)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b7479337-49c6-416e-a4ce-fb4e66990311/export-xaml-page-to-documentpdf-or-docs-or-xps?forum=wpdevelop
https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/114548/convert-xaml-to-pdf

Answer (score 0):

The dialog cannot be averted.  The solution is to convert the XAML to PDF yourself.

See [Converting XAML to PDF in an UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688156/converting-xaml-to-pdf-in-an-uwp-app/45739615#45739615)