# How to get TextBox value in template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a simple file manager. I try to open a new directory, by double-click on `ListBox`. How I can get `secondtb1.Text` property value in my code using `MouseDoubleClick`?

My XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="secondPageListbox" Background="{x:Null}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="320"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="186"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
               <TextBlock x:Name="secondtb1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Column="1">
               <TextBlock x:Name="secondtb2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding current.Extension}"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Column="2">
               <TextBlock x:Name="secondtb3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding creationTime}"/>
            </Grid>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
         <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="SecondListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Since you seem do be doing event handling in the code behind, you can just use `secondtb2.Text` in the code behind

Comment: But I have a lot of secondtb1 in listbox

Comment: Oh, in that case use a command instead and pass the current binding into it

Answer (score 0):

If you want get textbox content value:

```
secondtb2.Text;
```

You can use this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then you enumerate over the controls like so:

```
foreach (TextBlock textBlock in FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(window))
{
    textBlock.Text; // your text from TextBlock
}
```

If you're trying to get this to work and finding that your Window (for instance) has 0 visual children, try running this method in the Loaded event handler. If you run it in the constructor (even after InitializeComponent()), the visual children aren't loaded yet, and it won't work.
Link to source: [Find all controls in WPF Window by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)