# Loop through Groupbox in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF with contain tab control (page1, **page2**, and page3).

In tab control page 2, I do have 3 groupbox (**groupbox_A**, **groupbox_B**, and **groupbox_C**), and each of the groupbox contain **3 textbox**.

May I know what is the C# code to loop through all the textbox and clear the content.

Comment: Have you tried something like groupbox_A.textbox1.clear() ?

Comment: Initial code was using the code as mention (textbox1.clear()). With considering near to 60 textbox present, it will be tough to maintain the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will return all the textboxes within the tab control.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can get all text boxes by enumerating like this :

```
foreach (var textbox in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(window))
{
    // do something with tb here
}
```

Source : [Find all controls in WPF Window by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. It seem like I need to ensure the tab page 2 was activated so that the textbox store within page 2 will been clear.

Comment: I do have stackpanel_1 with orientation set to vertical. In the stackpanel_1, it consist of stackpanel_A, B, C, & D, with orientation set to horizontal and contain a few button. Some how code like foreach (stackepanel stkpnl in stackpanel_1.Children) was work.

Comment: The same thing happens here too. See `for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {`

Comment: Glad to have helped you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn`t look like a good approach.. find another logic to clear your texts.. but if you just want to know how it would work...

the easiest way:

```
IEnumerable<myType> collection = control.Children.OfType<myType>();
```

(control is the root element of the window and myType would be groubBox in your case)

The microsoft way to get through all elements [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx):

```
 // Enumerate all the descendants of the visual object.
 static public void EnumVisual(Visual myVisual)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
     {
        // Retrieve child visual at specified index value.
        Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);

        // Do processing of the child visual object.

        // Enumerate children of the child visual object.
        EnumVisual(childVisual);
    }
 }
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more on the easiest way and Microsoft way as I still try to pick up the C# skill and apply to my job. (I use to practice in VB and just 2 week ago, I started with C#.)