# FindLogicalNode fails when searching in RibbonWindow

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am searching a control using `LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode` in a `RibbonWindow`.  The element I am searching yields the error: Specified method is not supported. If the `Ribbon` control is removed from XAML or if it is moved behind the `TextBlock` `FindLogicalNode` works fine. Has anyone an explanation?

Here's the XAML:

```
<RibbonWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Ribbon Grid.Row="0"/> <!-- if moved behind the TextBox or removed it works -->
    <TextBox Name="myTextBox" />
</Grid>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)System.Windows.LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(this, "myTextBox");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the a helper method that finds the `TextBox` in the *visual* tree once it has been loaded:

[Find all controls in WPF Window by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)

```
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += (s, e) => 
        {
            TextBox textBox = FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(this).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "myTextBox");
        };
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the work-around. Do you have any clue why FindLogicalNode fails?

Comment: Because the TextBox is not found in the *logical* tree.