# Referencing a control found in Locals window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-behind

I've got a GridView that shows up in my Locals window.  The path I take is:

```
This -->   
  DataGrid_AA -->
    Controls -->
      Results View -->
        [0] -->
          Controls -->
            Results View -->
              [0] -->    
                Cells -->
                  Results View -->
                    [2] --> X
```

How would I go about referencing "X" in code?  I tried:

```
string x = this.DataGrid_AA.Controls[0].Controls[0].Cells[2].Text;
```

but it tells me "Control does not contain a definition for Cells".  Any ideas?

Comment: In WPF we have [`VisualTreeHelper`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/978352/1997232), in winforms you have to implement it yourself (check type to see what property contains children, repeat recursively until needed control is found by some criteria).

Comment: I can't actually test as I don't have time to set up the grid with the correct control hierarchy... but try  var myTargetControl = this.dataGridView1.Controls.Find("ControlName", true);   The "true" says search all children... I'm sure I used this to grab a drop down once on a grid..

Comment: If you know for sure what type `this.DataGrid_AA.Controls[0].Controls[0]` is, then simply cast (pseudo-code): `((DataGrid)this.DataGrid_AA.Controls[0].Controls[0]).Cells...`