# Wpf find all Controls by tag and type

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to retrieve of all elements by type and tag name. I already found some examples:

[How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type/1759923#1759923)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/978352/7444801

I tried to modify some of those examples but, they never gave me the result I wanted.

example of desired method:

```
public static Collection<T> FindAll<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
where T : DependencyObject
{ 
//code that gives me the collection 
}
```

Example desired tag object:

```
<Ellipse  Tag="tagname" Fill="Blue"  Width="25" Height="25" />
<Ellipse  Tag="tagname" Fill="Blue"  Width="25" Height="25" />
<Ellipse  Tag="tagname" Fill="Blue"  Width="25" Height="25" />
```

Method that I Tried:

```
public static Collection<T> FindAll<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
where T : DependencyObject
    {
        Collection<T> result=null;

        Boolean b = true;
        int c = 0;
        while (b)
        {
            T obj = FindChild<T>(parent, childName, c,-1);
            if (obj == null) b = false;
            else
            {
                if(result == null) result = new Collection<T>();
                result.Add(obj);
            }
            c++;
        }
        return result;
    }`
      `     /**
      * Param c = count of desired object
     * Param indchild= keeps cound (give negative for calling function)
     * */
    public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName,int c, int indchild)
where T : DependencyObject
    {
        // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
        if (parent == null) return null;

        T foundChild = null;

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
       if(indchild<=-1)indchild = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            // If the child is not of the request child type child
            T childType = child as T;
            if (childType == null)
            {
                // recursively drill down the tree
                foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName,c,indchild);

                // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                if (foundChild != null) break;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
            {
                var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                // If the child's name is set for search
                if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Tag!=null && ((String)frameworkElement.Tag).Equals(childName))
                {
                    // if the child's name is of the request name

                    if (c == indchild) { 
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                   }
                    indchild++;
                }
            }
        }

        return foundChild;
    }
```

Comment: So what did you try? The empty method that you have posted?

Comment: And what do you mean by "tag name"?

Comment: just added some more context to the post @mm8

Comment: Don't do it this way. You're torturing yourself for no reason. Whatever you want to achieve, there's a better way. Let's go back to the moment before you thought of writing code to search for the `Ellipse` elements. What was your goal then? What were you trying to accomplish?

Comment: it's kinda complicated but let' try. so i have X number of Ellipses that can have X number of different Tagnames. The goal is to change the color of those ellipses by tag name

Comment: @VincentN So you might have twelve ellipses named "Francisco" and six named "Benito", and you want to change all the ones named "Benito" to green.

Comment: yes indeed, but mm8 posted the solution, althought thanks helping!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following `FindVisualChildren` method:

[Find all controls in WPF Window by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)

...and simply filter the results:

```
string tagName = "tagname";
IEnumerable<Ellipse> elements = FindVisualChildren<Ellipse>(this).Where(x => x.Tag != null && x.Tag.ToString() == tagName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried a lot of solutions recommended by the community. None really worked. Had to modify a bit. Here is what worked for me.

```
            List<LayoutPanel> panels = new List<LayoutPanel>();
        foreach (object rawChild in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(dockManager))
        {
            if (rawChild is DependencyObject)
            {
                DependencyObject child = (DependencyObject)rawChild;
                if (child is LayoutPanel)
                {
                    panels.Add((LayoutPanel)child);
                }

                foreach (LayoutPanel childOfChild in FindLogicalChildren<LayoutPanel>(child))
                {
                    panels.Add(childOfChild);
                }
            }
        }
        var requiredPanel = panels.Where(t => t.Tag.ToString() == tagName).FirstOrDefault();
```