# WPF c# Hangman game : fill the missing letters

Tags: c#, wpf

Okay here is my code, I will explain it afterwards :

```
        private void TypedWord_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBoxResult confirmatBoxResult = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Are you sure ?", "Confirm", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
        if (confirmatBoxResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {

            for (char i = 'a'; i < 'z'; i++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Content = i;
                btn.Width = 60;
                btn.Height = 60;
                btn.FontSize = 36;
                btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnLetter_Click);
                panel_lettre.Children.Add(btn);
            }


            foreach (char c in txtMot.Text)
            {
                Label Lbl = new Label();
                Lbl.Content = c;
                Lbl.Content = "_";
                Lbl.FontSize = 36;
                Lbl.Width = 30;
                panel_label.Children.Add(Lbl);
            }

            TypedWord_Click.IsEnabled = false;

        }

    }

    private void btnLetter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I am the button : " + ((Button)sender).Content.ToString());
    }

}
```

**TypedWord_Click** is my button once you click on it, it shows you dynamically all the 26 letters of the alphabet **that are buttons**.

And after that, upside of it, I have a div where I put dynamically labels.
And these labels come from **txtMot.text**, which is a textbox that get the user input.

Then I change these words into an underscore **"_"**.

So if I type : "test" it will show : **_ _ _ _**
According to each letter from my word.

---

Under it there is an event on click : **btnLetter_Click**, that simply shows in a message box each letter according to their button.

So if I click on "a" it'll show => **I am the button a**

The thing is for this last thing it isn't really what I am looking for do.
I would like to fill my missing letters from the textbox **txtMot.Text** according to what the user typed.

So if I write "test" it will show => _ _ _ _ => from the label.

Then I have my 26 alphabet letters.

And here it is : how can I make that if I click on let's say "t", then it fill it like this => t_ _ t ?

Comment: You can't with your code, you're adding the labels to the form without a name, tag or anything else to identify them and you're replacing the content (the char) with "_" so you will not be able to know which label you must fill. You can use the `Tag` property to store the char for each label and then search for the controls with that tag, something like what is proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138015/wpf-find-all-controlles-by-tag-and-type

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative to going through each `Label` to find the matching letter.

Uses buckets of `Label`s for each letter, similar to a `Radix sort`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Look up label elements by letter
    var labelsLookupByLetter = new Dictionary<char, List<Label>>();

    var buttonsPanel = new UniformGrid
    {
        Columns = 8,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
    };
    for (var c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
    {
        var ch = c;
        var cmd = new Button
        {
            Content = c,
            Width = 24,
            Height = 24
        };
        buttonsPanel.Children.Add(cmd);
        labelsLookupByLetter[ch] = new List<Label>();
        cmd.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (labelsLookupByLetter.TryGetValue(ch, out var textList))
            {
                foreach (var el in textList)
                {
                    el.Content = ch;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    // Text panel
    var labelsPanel = new WrapPanel();
    var text = "helloworld";
    foreach (var ch in text)
    {
        var textBlock = new Label
        {
            Content = "_"
        };
        labelsLookupByLetter[ch].Add(textBlock);
        labelsPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
    }

    Content = new StackPanel
    {
        Children = { labelsPanel, buttonsPanel }
    };
}
```

[image]