# Find label by tag in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to locate a label by its tag so i can add an additional label beside when a certain condition is met.

in old school winform i would just use:

```
Label sublabel = Controls.Find(Sub.id, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
```

snippet of the view.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Label 
        Content = "{Binding Path = NodeName, Mode = OneWay}" 
        Background = "{Binding Path = NodeStatus, Mode = OneWay}"
        Tag="{Binding Path = Nodeid, Mode = OneWay}"
```

i have tried something along these lines:

```
var label = Grid.Children.OfType<Label>()
    .First(i => i.Tag == "tagid");
```

but generates

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Panel.Children'
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type

Comment: In MVVM you shouldn't be manipulating the view like that. Seems like you should be setting a flag, or updating a string in the VM that causes the view to do what you want

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44138544/177416

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could give the `Grid` an `x:Name` in your XAML markup:

```
<Grid x:Name="theGrid">
```

...and refer to it by this name in your code:

```
var label = theGrid.Children.OfType<Label>() ...
```

Note that this is not MVVM by any means though. Using MVVM, you would access the `Nodeid` source property rather than the `Tag` property of the `Label` element.