# How to get the current running page in WPF Frame

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a dashboard `Window` that contain a `Frame`, This frame hold a lot of pages,
In particular point how can I get the current page that loaded in the frame

Hope this clear

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/978352

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current `Page` from the `Content` property of the `Frame`:

```
Page currentPage = frame1.Content as Frame;
```