# How do i convert System.Windows.Media.Visual to System.Windows.Controls.Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

My goal is to send a wpf control and enable or disable all controls in its container.

I found this code in stack overflow and i can loop alla elements but i dont now
how to convert it to a System.Windows.Control so that i can set the isEnabled flag:

```
public static void EnableAllControls(Visual control, int level,bool enable)
{
    const int indent = 4;
    int ChildNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);


    for (int i = 0; i <= ChildNumber - 1; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);


        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(v) > 0)
        {
            EnableAllControls(v, level + 1,enable);
        }

        //var ctr = v.GetType as System.Windows.Controls.Control; -> this gives runtime error.
        //ctr.IsEnabled = enable;
    }

}
```

I quess it should be possible - does anyone now how?

Comment: What does "send a control" mean? Send it where?

Comment: Could you try ``var ctr = v as System.Windows.Controls.Control`` instead?

Comment: @Caius Jard i meant i just want to set it to IsEnable true or false, not send it in that sense - when i said send i meant to the function

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type - how did it not meet your needs, if you have?