# After making whole form disable, how to set one button to be enable?

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

I'm using WPF, and I have a form, on which there are many textboxes, buttons and whatnot.

For a specific reason I need that whole form to be disabled, which I managed with the code below -

```
public WPForm() //constructor
    {
        this.IsEnabled = false;            
    }
```

But, I have one button that sends me back to another form, which I need to be enabled (clickable), and what I have tried is simply setting it like this -

```
public WPForm() //constructor
    {
        this.IsEnabled = false;   
        btnBack.IsEnabled = true;         
    }
```

And this does basically nothing, so my question is, what else do I need to do in order to make it enabled?

Comment: `foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls.Where(c => c.Name != "btnBack"))
    ctrl.IsEnabled = false;` to be honest, you should be using utilizing mvvm with binding.

Comment: I don't have this.Controls option

Comment: `wpf` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type

Comment: WPF, as I put in the tags

Comment: Naming your `Window` `Form` and saying `I have a form` doesn't give me anything useful, I would assume `WinForms`, not `WPF`. Anyways, I would go the MVVM path and use binding for this as I've mentioned already.

Comment: Yeah, maybe check the tag section, as I've mentioned already. Anyway, question is edited. Thanks for advice about MVVM, but I'm sure I can work with this just fine.

Comment: `maybe check the tag section` you have both, doesn't help.

Comment: No I don't. There is no WinForms, nor ever was. Form is indeed part of WPF.

Comment: `Form` isn't a part of the `WPF` framework(please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/windows-forms-controls-and-equivalent-wpf-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), it's part of `WinForms`. Why did you change your class name to `WinForm`?

Comment: Please take my advice I've given to help. Hope it all works out, good luck!

Comment: My bad, I got my brain busted staring at a PC whole day. Will take into considering, but still searching for something "simpler".

Comment: `but still searching for something "simpler"` please re-read my comments. It doesn't take much to do what I've recommended (mvvm/binding) and is preferred; start with it now rather than later.

Answer (score -2):

Just dont set the whole Form to disabled.
Try to put a Grid or Stackpanel around the Controls that need to be disabled and disable them only. Maybe like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    //Your Controls
<Grid/>
<Button />


public WinForm() //constructor
{
    myGrid.IsEnabled = false;         
}
```

Comment: Why even do this, instead of the constructor doing this, why not just set the property itself. What happens when some other conditions change and perhaps need to change the state of other controls in this grid?