# Set Text attribute of multiple TextBlocks

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to set the `Text` attribute of multiple `TextBlock`s without calling each one separately? The possibility to iterate through them?

Like in the following example:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textblock_a" Text="Original text"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="textblock_b" Text="Original text"/>
```

To

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textblock_a" Text="Modified text"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="textblock_b" Text="Modified text"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF: How do I loop through the all controls in a window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874380/wpf-how-do-i-loop-through-the-all-controls-in-a-window)

Comment: Bind their `Text` property to a single view model property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way:

```
foreach(var item in new[] {textblock_a, textblock_b})
    item.Text = "Modified text";
```

P.S.: I wouldn't use word *attribute* without mentioning `xaml`, `Text` is a *property*.

Answer (score 3):

The WPF way of doing this is by using Binding.

As state [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx)(easy example) you can bind the `Text` value of your `TextBlocks` to the same property.

Do not forget the `INotifyPropertyChanged` so everything updates when the string changes.