# Access WPF window control from another assembly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a library DLL, and a WPF test exe that depends on the said library.  Here's the test exe:

```
using MyLibrary;

namespace WpfTest
{
    public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        private MyLibrary _mylib;

        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += window2Loaded;
        }

        void window2Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _mylib = new MyLibrary(this);
        }
    }
}
```

In the MyLibrary class (in the DLL), I have the following constructor:

```
    public MyLibrary (System.Windows.Window window) // BREAKPOINT HERE.
    {
        ...
```

At the breakpoint above, the debugger shows the `TextBlock` (tb_mp) I want to access:

[image]

What do i need to do so that when I type `window.tb_` in Visual Studio, IntelliSense will offer to complete it as `window.tb_mp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing, you can't. The Locals widnow shows an envelope icon next to the `tb_mp` local, that means it's an `internal` member (see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.100).aspx ). Visual Studio's intellisense window won't list members you don't have access to, in this case, `internal` members from another project.

There are three options:

1. Change the access-modifier (in the original project) to `public`
2. Use reflection to access the field (e.g. `FieldInfo fi = window.GetType().GetField("tb_mp")`)
3. Iterate through controls in a window by using `VisualTreeHelper`. This is a more complicated topic, discussed at length here: [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type) and here: [WPF: How do I loop through the all controls in a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874380/wpf-how-do-i-loop-through-the-all-controls-in-a-window)

Comment: Thank you. To this day I was unaware of the envelope icon, let alone knew its meaning! Providing `x:FieldModifier="public"` for `tb_mp` opened up access to it, but I also had to cast the `window` variable as `((WpfTest.Window2)` (as well as supply the namespace, of course) for IntelliSense to kick in.