# C# WPF set Tag=name for all controls

Tags: c#, wpf, tags

I have a project with various controls some with a name and some without.
I want to loop though all controls and automatically set Tag=Name when present.
I have seen various solution like this one:

[WPF: How do I loop through the all controls in a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874380/wpf-how-do-i-loop-through-the-all-controls-in-a-window)

and this works but then I can't get to set :

```
foreach (Visual ctrl in MainGrid.GetChildren())
{
    ctrl.Tag = ctrl.Name;<------
}
```

To me the tag is used recognize the event es when pressing different buttons.
Thanx
Patrick

Comment: Unclear. What does and doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tag` property only exists on `FrameworkElements`

So you need to make a cast :

```
foreach (Visual ctrl in MainGrid.GetChildren())
{
    FrameworkElement fxElt = ctrl as FrameworkElement;
    if( fxElt != null)
        fxElt.Tag = fxElt.Name;
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanx that works. You just forgot to change the last line. It's not fxElt.Tag = ctrl.Name; but fxElt.Tag = fxElt.Name;