# How to use foreach (Control c in this.Controls) in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

How Can I use this code in WPF:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{

}
```

(I want to change opacity of elements one after another!)

Comment: Whats went wrong when you tried?

Comment: I don't know why people mark down questions.. this is a legit question to me.

Comment: Thanks. me too! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF doesn't have the concept of controls the same way WinForms does.
You need to determine if it's a ContentControl or a Panel.  ContentControl has Content of object and Panel has Children of UIElement.

Look at my answer on this question... I show how to cycle the controls and I explain it as well.

[Link to Get all Controls with explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121494/list-all-controls-of-a-specific-window-of-wpf/43197044#43197044)

Comment: @amirhossein What do you mean?  That is a compiled working example that I posted.  If you're not using C# 7 then I recommend you upgrade to use it... If not then you'll have to tweak it some for the C# version you're using.  Other than the syntax it should work just fine.  I've used this recursive type search for years in WPF.

Comment: Not a problem.  Glad to help.