# Can I Iterate the Controls of ContentDialog?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to iterate all of controls of contentdialog if available.

because I want to get and set Tag Property of each controls in a contentdialog.

for example,

```
    public ContentDialog MyDialog = new ContentDialog
    {
        Title = "My Title",
        Content = "My Content",
        PrimaryButtonText = "OK",
        SecondaryButtonText = "Cancel",
    };
```

for example pseudo code,

```
void DeepFirstSearch(ContentDialog IN_pMyDialog, DependencyObject IN_pControl)
{
    foreach (pControl in IN_pMyDialog)
    {
       if ( pControl is TextBlock )
       {
         ...
       }
       else if ( pControl is Button )
       {
         ...
       }

       if (pControl.GetChildCount() > 0)
       {
         DeepFirstSearch(IN_pDialog, pControl)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874380/wpf-how-do-i-loop-through-the-all-controls-in-a-window

Comment: thanks for comment, but VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount() returns 0 unlike other controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Visual Tree in a ContentDialog so there are no children.  You want to iterate through its properties, you can do that with reflection.

```
var cd = new ContentDialog();
var cdProps = cd.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var propInfo in cdProps)
{
    if (typeof(Button).IsAssignableFrom(propInfo.PropertyType))
    {
        var button = (Button)(cd.GetType().GetProperty(propInfo.Name).GetValue(cd, null));
        // Do stuff with it
    }
    if (typeof(TextBlock).IsAssignableFrom(propInfo.PropertyType))
    {
        var textBlock = (TextBlock)(cd.GetType().GetProperty(propInfo.Name).GetValue(cd, null));
        // Do stuff with it
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and it solved. i got an idea, however, that code not worked, so i modified a little.

Comment: public void Reflection(ContentDialog IN_pObject)
        {
            var cdProps = IN_pObject.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var propInfo in cdProps)
            {
                string strTypeName = propInfo.ToString().Split(' ')[0];

                if (strTypeName == "System.String" || propInfo.Name == "Title" || propInfo.Name == "Content")
                {
         //TODO
                       IN_pObject.GetType().GetProperty(propInfo.Name).SetValue("TODO");
                }
            }
        }